# JavaScript: Select elements with data value in range of X and Y

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, calendar, jquery-data

I am creating a calendar and need to be able to select (to show/hide) `div.event` who's `data-dates` (which may be string or array, depending on number of days the event appears in) by determining if any of the unix timestamp dates stored there are such that they fall between the unix timestamps which represent the start and end of the currently chosen month. So for example:

It is April 2013, so I wish to see only events that occur in April (`1364774400` [April 1st, midnight] and `1367366399` [April 30th, 23:59:59]).

I have many `event` divs. They look something like this:

```
<div class="event" data-dates="[1367539200, 1367625600]">...</div>
<div class="event" data-dates="[1364947200]">...</div>
```

Let's assume one or more of those have timestamps that fall sometime in April 2013. How do I select them?

Comment: Looks like a job for .filter http://api.jquery.com/filter/ select all event divs, then filter with a custom callback that loops through and compares dates.

Comment: I doubt that this can be accomplished with pure selectors...

Comment: @KevinB looking into this

Comment: Might be best if you modified the code that creates the DIVs to add `data-month` attributes.

Comment: @Barmar True, would reduce complexity of this selection, but I will later need to have a method for selecting a `week` or `day` at a time, so I thought this `data-dates` method would work for all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to make use of `filter`:

```
var rangeStart = 1364774400,
    rangeEnd   = 1367366399;

$('.event').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('dates').some(function(date) {
        return date >= rangeStart && date < rangeEnd;
    });
})
.addClass('active');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HJ9Xj/1/

*Note. [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method is not available in IE<9 so you can shim it or use simple `for` loop to check if data array contains any value between `start` and `end`. [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ9Xj/2/).*

Comment: `var monthStart = new Date(y, m, 1);` `var monthEnd = new Date(y, m +1, 0);` Then what?

Comment: Woohoo thank you for going the extra mile with that second demo! Works beautifully.